# Converting ddply syntax into data.table

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I have a 1.3 million row data frame which I need to aggregate into regional and temporal summaries. `Plyr`'s syntax is straightforward, but it's just much too slow to be practical (I've left `ddply` to run for an hour, and it's completed less than 25%). I'm looking for help translating the `ddply` syntax into `data.table` to exploit its vaunted speed.

My data are of the following type

```
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)

dat <- expand.grid(area = letters[1:2],
                    day = as.Date("2012-10-01") + c(0:10) * days(1),
                   type = paste("t", 1:2, sep=""))
dat$val <- runif(44)
```

I need row counts (which will be equal here, given my toy data) and sums of the `val` variable for different periods.

This `ddply` call gives me what I'm looking for

```
count.and.sum <- function(i){
  if(i$day >= as.Date("2012-10-02")){
     k <- data.frame(c_1d = nrow(dat[dat$type == i$type &
                                     dat$area == i$area &
                                     dat$day %in% i$day - days(1),]),
                     c_2d = nrow(dat[dat$type == i$type &
                                     dat$area == i$area &
                                     dat$day %in% (i$day - c(1:2) * days(1)),]),
                     s_1d = sum(dat$val[dat$type == i$type &
                                        dat$area == i$area &
                                        dat$day %in% i$day - days(1)]),
                     s_2d = sum(dat$val[dat$type == i$type &
                                        dat$area == i$area &
                                        dat$day %in% (i$day - c(1:2) * days(1))]))
  return(k) 
  }
 }

ddply(dat, .(area, day, type), count.and.sum)[1:10,]
```

Would really appreciate any `data.table` syntax you could provide.

Comment: Look at the .SD argument to data.table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your function is terribly inefficient and exposes a lack of understanding of what a function to be passed to plyr should look like. For ddply(), it should take a generic data frame as input and output a data frame. By 'generic' in this context, I mean a data frame that would be produced as any one of the 'splits' defined by combinations of the levels of the grouping variables. Your function should look more like this:

```
count.and.sum <- function(d) data.frame(n = length(d$val), valsum = sum(d$val))
```

The grouping variable combinations are taken care of in the ddply() call.

Secondly, your `ddply()` call creates one line data frames because each observation is associated with a unique combination of area, day and type. A more realistic application of `ddply()` for this toy example would be to summarize by day:

Direct method using `summarise` as the 'apply' function:

```
ddply(dat, .(day), summarise, nrow = length(val), valsum = sum(val))
```

Using `count.and.sum`:

```
ddply(dat, .(day), count.and.sum)
```

This is very likely to be much faster than your version of `count.and.sum`.

As for an equivalent data.table version (not necessarily the most efficient), try this:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat, key = c('area', 'day', 'type'))

DT[, list(n = length(val), valsum = sum(val)), by = 'day']
```

Here's a slightly more elaborate toy example with 100K observations:

```
set.seed(5490)
dat2 <- data.frame(area = sample(letters[1:2], 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                   day = sample(as.Date("2012-10-01") + c(0:10) * days(1),
                                  1e5, replace = TRUE),
                   type = sample(paste0("t", 1:2), 1e5, replace = TRUE),
                   val = runif(1e5))

system.time(u <- ddply(dat2, .(area, day, type), summarise, 
                      n = length(val), valsum = sum(val)))

DT2 <- data.table(dat2, key = c('area', 'day', 'type'))
system.time(v <- DT2[, list(n = length(val), valsum = sum(val)), by = key(DT)])

identical(u, as.data.frame(v))
```

On my system, the `data.table` version is about 4.5 times faster than the `plyr` version (0.09s elapsed for plyr, 0.02 for data.table).

Comment: Use `.N` instead of `length(val)` with data.table.